# Euclidean algorithm on $(a^n-1,a^m-1)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I'm having trouble applying the Euclidean algorithm to
$$\gcd(a^n-1,a^m-1)=a^{\gcd(n,m)}-1$$
I've seen others do it such as in [this solution](/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1/1496578) but I'm having trouble figuring out what they are doing in each step.

Could someone help explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $n=qm+r$. Then $ a^n-1 = a^r\cdot(a^m)^q-1 $, and since
$$ a^m \equiv 1 \pmod{a^m-1} \tag{1}$$
we have:
$$ (a^n-1) \equiv (a^r-1)\pmod{a^m-1}\tag{2} $$
proving:
$$ \gcd(a^n-1,a^m-1) = \gcd(a^r-1,a^m-1).\tag{3}$$
Now, repeat. The involved exponents transform like in the computation of
$$ \gcd(n,m) = \gcd(r,m) = \ldots \tag{4} $$ 
hence at last we get:
$$ \gcd(a^n-1,a^m-1) = a^{\gcd(n,m)}-1\tag{5} $$
qed.