# Greatest common divisor of $X^n-1$ and $X^m-1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Let $f=X^n-1$ and $g=X^m-1$ be two polynomials. Show that:
$$\left(f,g\right)=X^{\left(n,m\right)}-1,$$
where $\left(a,b\right)=$ greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: I'm supposed to use the Euclidean Division but I'm getting nowhere.

Comment: Try the standard: that is to show that $d=(x,y)$ show that $d$ divides $x$ and $y$ and that every $d'$ that divides $x$ and $y$ also dvides $d$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that $\gcd(a^n - 1, a^m - 1) = a^{\gcd(n, m)} - 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1) and [Euclidean algorithm on $(a^n-1,a^m-1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2129562/euclidean-algorithm-on-an-1-am-1)

Comment: Consider their roots of unity.

Comment: How am I supposed to show that there are $(n,m)$ identic roots?

Comment: And will the answer change if we consider GCD over $\mathbb{C} [X] $?

Comment: @GraduateStudent The gcd remains same over extension fields, this is in covered in textbooks, just notice that gcd d_L  of f, g in larger field has to divide gcd d_S in smaller field as d_S=af+bg. Also, d_L  should have degree larger than d_S as d_S is also there in larger field.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose m and n have a common divisor like k such that $m=m_1k$ and $n=n_1k$ then we can write:

$x^n-1=x^{n_1k}-1=(x^k-1)(x^{n_1k-k}+x^{{n_1k-2k}}+ \ldots+ {x^{n_1k-(n_1-1)k}}+1)$

$x^m-1=x^{m_1k}-1=(x^k-1)(x^{m_1k-k}+x^{{m_1k-2k}}+ \ldots +{x^{m_1k-(m_1-1)k}}+1)$

Which their common divisor  is..$(f,g)=(x^k-1)$ or $(f,g)=x^{gcd(m,n)}-1$